# C# Speaker Output Device *Advanced* Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, device

I have a C# (WPF) application which checks for all output devices (Speakers) and I need to check the Bit Depth and Sample Rate of the output device. Has anyone worked with this or know of a way to do so?

I have been searching around, but found nothing similar...

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The output device is not bound to a particular bit depth or sample rate, it plays whatever it is asked to. Do you mean to find the currently playing values ? Or to get the maximum bit depth and sample rate the device can handle ?

Comment: Yes, I mean to find the currently playing values.. is there a way to retrieve this information in C#/WPF? I am at a loss at the moment..